# SQLite: How to get average of long type values

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm making an app that records the timestamp of touchscreen actions made my the user.

Then, after recording the readings in an SQLite table, I take the average of each column at the end. However, I'm getting an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1344): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1.40024e+08"
```

This happens when I try to take the average of each column, which I'm doing like so:

```
public long[] getAvg()
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  AVG(dwell_1), AVG(dwell_2), AVG(dwell_3),  AVG(dwell_4), AVG(dwell_5), AVG(dwell_6), AVG(dwell_7), AVG(dwell_8), AVG(dwell_9), AVG(flight_12), AVG(flight_23), AVG(flight_34), AVG(flight_45), AVG(flight_56), AVG(flight_67), AVG(flight_78), AVG(flight_89) FROM " + TABLE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    long[] row = new long[17];

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int j=0; j<17; j++)
            row[j] =  Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(j));


    }

    return row;

}
```

It seems to be a function of the way the SQLite query displays the results. Is there any way I can circumvent/solve this? I require the precision by the way, so I can't use int or something else instead.

Oddly enough, when I run a query to just straight up display every record in the table, it works fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exception is here?  row[j] =  Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(j));

Comment: you must be writing a float value to that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 public long[] getAvg()
 {
      String selectQuery = "SELECT  AVG(dwell_1), AVG(dwell_2), AVG(dwell_3),  AVG(dwell_4), AVG(dwell_5), AVG(dwell_6), AVG(dwell_7), AVG(dwell_8), AVG(dwell_9), AVG(flight_12), AVG(flight_23), AVG(flight_34), AVG(flight_45), AVG(flight_56), AVG(flight_67), AVG(flight_78), AVG(flight_89) FROM " + TABLE;

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      long[] row = new long[17];

      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          for (int j=0; j<17; j++)
               row[j] =  cursor.getLong(j);
      }

      return row;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe `SQLite`AVG() function returns a `float` value which you are trying to parse it as `Long`, hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite returns float result, which you are trying to save to long.

Possible solutions:

1. Use float/double variables on Java side.
2. Or force SQLite to output integer/long using

   ```
   SELECT CAST(avg(field) AS INTEGER) AS avg_field...
   ```

   In your case, result should still fit into Java long if original was SQLite INTEGER.

Comment: It works if I read it as `cursor.getLong(j)` - thanks for the explanation though. +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple method that fetches the average rating of an entity. The rating float value is stored between 0.0 to 5.0.

```
  public static float getAverageReviews(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  SUM(stars) * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_STORE_REVIEWS;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        float totalSum = 0;
        if(count > 0 && c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StoreReviews.KEY_STARS));
                totalSum  += Float.parseFloat(result);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
        return totalSum/count;
    }
```